# Cordova connect to socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**Hello everyone**, i'm facing an issue that I can't solve. I'm using apache cordova to make an app on my android I have a Node.js server hosted on the web. So on my app I want to connect to the socket. On my computer if I open the app through my navigator (microsoft edge) it's working as expected.

But when I install the app on my android device it doesn't connect to the socket. Because on the server I see that no one is connected and nothings happens with the socket in the app. Note that the app doesn't seems to have error because I printed the console on the screen and there is no error.

My simple Node.js server :

```js
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const io = socketIO(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET"]
  }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("An user has connected");

  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    io.emit('message', msg);
    console.log("received : " + msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log("An user has disconnected");
  })
});

server.listen(3456, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3456");
});
```

in app code to connect to the server :

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-9mpsATI0KClwt+xVZfbcf2lJ8IFBAwsubJ6mI3rtULwyM3fBmQFzj0It4tGqxLOGQwGfJdk/G+fANnxfq9/cew==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var socket = io.connect('http://MYSERVER:3456');

                $("form").submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    socket.emit("message", $("#messageContent").val());
                    $("#messageContent").val("");

                    return false;
                })

                socket.on('message', function(msg) {
                    console.log("receiving");
                    $("MessageContainer").append($("<div class='MessageBox'>").text(msg));
                })
            })
        </script>
```

My config.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ddc.ddc" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>ddc</name>
    <description>Sample Apache Cordova App</description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="https://cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-navigation href="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
</widget>
```

And finnaly my meta in the head

```html
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;">
```

Maybe I miss some settings with cordova during the build ? I use android studio to build directly on my android device.

***Thanks you for your help***